# Jenkins withCredentials in dynamic selected parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy

could you help me with a litle throuble?

I tried find solution  with jenkins and your wonderful plugin: uno-choice, but I couldn't it.

I have very simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
def proc ='/var/lib/jenkins/script.sh location'.execute()

proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
proc.waitForOrKill(1000)

def credential(name) {
   def v;
   withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: name, usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
       v = "${env.USERNAME}"
   }
   return v
}

def key = credential('aws_prod_api')

String str = sout.toString()
String s = str.trim()
String[] items = s.split(",");
def v1 = Arrays.asList(items)
return v1
```

In general I want get AWS Credentional which save in Jenkins from bash script and with it do something.

I want use  withCredentials in block which make selected list, but I don't understand how I can do it.

Could you help me with it? 
I will very appreciate it

I tried using withCredentials inside groovy, but I got error:

> Fallback to default script... groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No
>   signature of method: Script1.withCredentials() is applicable for
>   argument types: (java.util.ArrayList, Script1$_credential_closure1)
>   values: [[[$class:UsernamePasswordMultiBinding,
>   credentialsId:aws_prod_api, ...]], ...]   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
>     at

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please trim this down to a minimal example? Your quote seems to include a lot of unrelated information, which makes it hard to inspect.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `withCredentials` does not exist in the scope of `Script1`. It exists in the scope of the `Jenkinsfile` DSL. You need to pass it in.

I suggest converting your script to functions. Then passing the `Jenkinsfile` DSL through to your Groovy code.

```
def doAwsStuff(dsl) {
   ...
   def key = credential(dsl, 'aws_prod_api')
   ...
}

def credential(dsl, name) {
   def v;
   dsl.withCredentials([[$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', credentialsId: name, usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD']]) {
       v = "${env.USERNAME}"
   }
   return v
}
```

and then call it from your `Jenkinsfile` with:

```
def result = MyAwsStuff.doAwsStuff(this)
```